# how to add android application to Addmob

Tags: android, admob

Firstly i have read all these links:
[google developper](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/), [tutorial-1](http://bigknol.com/android-google-analytics-api-v4-tutorial/),[google developper-2](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/parameters),[tutorial-2](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-google-analytics-v4-example/)

I did following:GpsMapActivity(banner admob should be here)(I dont show whole code here)

```
  public class GpsMapActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity implements OnMarkerClickListener, LocationListener,OnMapClickListener {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

Tracker t = ((GoogleAnalyticsApp) getApplication()).getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
        t.setScreenName("Home");
        t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
        t.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
}
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(GpsMapActivity.this).reportActivityStart(this);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(GpsMapActivity.this).reportActivityStop(this);
    }
}
```

GoogleAnalyticApplcation class

```
public class GoogleAnalyticsApp extends Application {

    private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "**my_admob_tracking_id_here";

    public static int GENERAL_TRACKER = 0;

    public enum TrackerName {
        APP_TRACKER, GLOBAL_TRACKER, ECOMMERCE_TRACKER,
    }

    public HashMap mTrackers = new HashMap();

    public GoogleAnalyticsApp() {
        super();
    }

    public synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName appTracker) {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(appTracker)) {
            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            Tracker t = (appTracker == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID) : (appTracker == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker) : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
            mTrackers.put(appTracker, t);
        }
        return (Tracker) mTrackers.get(appTracker);//If I dont cast tracker //here eclipse gives error.In tutorial there is no cast
    }
}
```

res/xml files:app_tracker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="ga_trackingId">**my_admob_tracking_id_here</string>

    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

    <string name="ga_appName">GoogleAnalyticsApp</string>
    <string name="ga_appVersion">1.1.3</string>

    <bool name="ga_debug">true</bool>

    <item name="ga_dispatchPeriod" format="integer" type="integer">120</item>

    <string name="ga_sampleFrequency">90</string>

    <bool name="ga_anonymizeIp">true</bool>
    <bool name="ga_dryRun">false</bool>

    <string name="ga_sampleFrequency">100.0</string>

    <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">-1</integer>

    <string name="turkiye.yollari.trafikolaylari">GoogleAnalyticsApp</string>

</resources>
```

ecommerce_tracker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">60</integer>
    <string name="ga_trackingId">**my_admob_tracking_id_here</string>
</resources>
```

global_trackker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>

    <!-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

    <!-- The screen names that will appear in reports -->
    <screenName name="turkiye.yollari.trafikolaylari.GpsMapActivity">
        GoogleAnalyticsApp ScreenViewSampleScreen
    </screenName>

    <!--  The following value should be replaced with correct property id. -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">**my_admob_tracking_id_here</string>
</resources>
```

android_manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="turkiye.yollari.trafikolaylari"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

     <permission
        android:name="com.example.socialnetworkatilimroads.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
     <uses-permission
        android:name="com.example.socialnetworkatilimroads.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission
        android:name="com.example.androidmapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application

        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" 
        android:name=".GoogleAnalyticsApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="turkiye.yollari.trafikolaylari.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="turkiye.yollari.trafikolaylari.RegisterationActivity" />
        <activity android:name="turkiye.yollari.trafikolaylari.RecoverPasswordActivity" />
        <activity android:name="turkiye.yollari.trafikolaylari.LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name="turkiye.yollari.trafikolaylari.GpsMapActivity" />

        <activity android:name="turkiye.yollari.trafikolaylari.BannedActivity" />
        <activity android:name="turkiye.yollari.trafikolaylari.MyAccountActivity" />
        <activity android:name="turkiye.yollari.trafikolaylari.AnnouncementsActivity" />

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAO2u35cPnPAve3KEjAzveQCd8PUxh2oPk" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

my application work with no crash but banner admob is not be shown.What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you haven't added anything to do with banner ads into your app. All of the code and links cited above are all to do with analytics, not ads.

You need to follow this: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start